# AWS Appflow timeout issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-appflow

I am getting a timeout issue using appflow to transfer sharepoint data to s3. Anyone know how to fix this issue (the flow is not programmable, it is manual) and increase the timeout settings on appflow or S3?

Here is an image of the error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq3Za.png)